# Eager-load Same Relationship, Different Constraints

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

In Eloquent, I'm trying to lazy-eager-load the same relationship twice, with different constraints.  The goal here is to learn two things about employee timesheets.  One is all the hours they worked in the last year.  The other is the first date they worked.

The first relation constraint is this:

```
$employeeTimeSheets = app(Timesheet::class)
    ->with([
        'punches' => function (Relation $query) {
            $query->where('punch_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYear());
        }
    ])
```

The second is:

```
$employeeTimeSheets = app(Timesheet::class)
    ->with([
        'punches' => function (Relation $query) {
            $query
                ->whereNotNull('punch_date')
                ->orderBy('punch_date')
                ->limit(1);
        }
    ])
```

The problem is of course 'punches' is only allowed once.  And there's going to be a few thousand employees being pulled here, so it's kind of important to me to be able to eager-load this data for the sake of performance.

These are kind of arbitrary conditions, just once place in the whole system where they come up.  So I'm not sure it warrants adding an entirely new relationship method to the Timesheet model.  And I'd also rather not pull *all* the punches for each employee just to extract the last year and the minimum after the fact, because that would be a mountain of data.

I'm not sure this would be possible to do this without overriding how Eloquent handles relationships to add support for an `as` keyword in the name.  But what I'm really going for is something that feels like this:

```
$employeeTimeSheets = app(Timesheet::class)
    ->with([
        'punches as last_year' => function (Relation $query) {
            $query->where('punch_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYear());
        },
        'punches as first_punch' => function (Relation $query) {
            $query
                ->whereNotNull('punch_date')
                ->orderBy('punch_date')
                ->limit(1);
        }
    ])
```

Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: I don't think adding a relationship for a single use case is a bad thing. I would argue that few relationships are used in more than two or three places.

Comment: I guess the thing that makes that feel off isn't so much the fact that it only serves one use-case.  It's that it *can* *only* serve one use-case.  Usually relation methods are capable of serving a generic purpose, even if only one thing happens to use it at the time it's set up.  But to add one with very specific behavior like this effectively couples the model to the implementation in a way that, while functional, feels like an anti-pattern.

Comment: How likely is it that your `punches as last_year` **do not** contain the latest punch as queried in `punches as first_punch`? Because if you can expect a punch to be available for each employee for the recent year, you don't really need the second relation. The first one would already contain the latter as subset. By the way, if you don't need both relations at the same time, you can also unset a loaded relation with `unset($model->relation)` or `$child->setRelations([])` for all relations. This also saves memory.

Comment: The `last_year` set encompasses all punches ranging from one year ago through to today.  Whereas the 'first_punch' will present the first-ever shift an employee had, even if it was 5 years ago.  So it's extremely likely they'll contain different data.  And I do need both at the same time.  I could simply do it with two separate queries, by extracting the Ids from the first to use in the second, so the inefficient search-criteria doesn't have to be re-queried.  And then connecting the results with `setRelations` into one big Collection.  But the solution below just felt a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  An override of some of the methods in the Model class to parse for the `as` keyword did the trick.  I stuffed all this into a trait, but it could just as easily be moved to a base class extended by all models, and itself extends Model:

```
/**
 * @uses \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 * @uses \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes
 * @uses \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships
 *
 * Trait RelationAlias
 */
trait RelationAlias
{
    protected $validOperators = [
        'as'
    ];

    /**
     * @param string $method
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if ($key = $this->parseKey($method)) {
            $method = $key['concrete'];
            if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                return $this->$method(...$parameters);
            }
        }

        return parent::__call($method, $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArrayableRelations()
    {
        $arrayableRelations = parent::getArrayableRelations();
        foreach ($arrayableRelations as $key => $value) {
            if ($aliased = $this->parseKey($key)) {
                $arrayableRelations[$aliased['alias']] = $value;
                unset($arrayableRelations[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $arrayableRelations;
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRelationValue($key)
    {
        if ($found = parent::getRelationValue($key)) {
            return $found;
        }

        $relations = array_keys($this->relations);
        foreach ($relations as $relation) {
            $aliased = $this->parseKey($relation);
            if ($aliased && $aliased['alias'] == $key) {
                if ($this->relationLoaded($relation)) {
                    return $this->relations[$relation];
                }

                if (method_exists($this, $aliased['concrete'])) {
                    return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return array|null
     */
    protected function parseKey($key)
    {
        $concrete = $operator = $alias = null;
        foreach ($this->validOperators as $operator) {
            if (preg_match("/.+ $operator .+/i", $key)) {
                list($concrete, $operator, $alias) = explode(' ', $key);
                break;
            }
        }

        return $alias ? compact('concrete', 'operator', 'alias') : null;
    }
}
```